# Searching for a string in a file in a different language - PHP - UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

I have read through many posts and tried many thing,

I have some monster files in a game server I am working on, 
The game is a korean game so a lot of the code words are in korean.

I am trying to get a line that starts with `*아이템` followed by the string I am wanting. I set the default_encoding to UTF-8. 
I am able to find the string based on other bits in it but I want to exclude that `*아이템` from my output,

sample for the code is:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
    $monsdbconn = sqlsrv_connect("INSTANCE\SQLEXPRESS", array("Database" => "MonsDB", "UID" => "BLAH", "PWD"=> "BLAH"));
    $monsDir = realpath('C:/PT-Server/GameServer/Monster/');
    $monsters = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($monsDir);

if (@$monsdbconn) {
    $clearit = "DELETE FROM monsdrops";
    if (sqlsrv_query($monsdbconn,$clearit)) {
        foreach($monsters as $name => $object){
            $monstername = "";  
            if (stripos($name, '.inf')){
                $monsterfile = file($name);
                $items = array("WA*", "WP*", "DA*", "WC*");
                foreach ($monsterfile as $monster) {
                    if (strstr($monster, "Name")) {
                        //things to remove from the string.
                        $monstrip = array("*Name",'"'); 

                        //Remove "" and *Name from the string
                        $monstername = str_replace($monstrip, "", $monster); 

                        //Remove spaces from start and end of string to prevent
                        //Duplicate entries, Will not remove space from between words.
                        $monstername = trim($monstername," "); // Space
                        $monstername = trim($monstername,"  "); // Tab
                    }
                    // THIS IS THE POINT IM SEARCHING FOR ITEMS AT THE MOMENT, BUT I NEED IT TO FIND THE KOREAN CHAR SET
                    if (preg_match("/\D{2}\d{3}/", $monster)) { 

                        $string = preg_split("/(\s)/", $monster);
                        foreach ($string as $line) {
                            if ((preg_match("/\D{2}\d{3}/", $line)) && ((stripos($line, "name\\") === false) || stripos($line, ".zhoon") === false)) {
                                $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO monsdrops ([monstername],[monsterdrops]) VALUES ('$monstername', '$line')";
                                $insert = sqlsrv_query($monsdbconn, $sqlinsert);
                                if ($insert) {
                                    echo "Insert $monstername, $line Successful! <br />";       
                                } else {
                                    echo "<br />Insert Failed! <br />";
                                    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }       
                }

            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Unable To Clear DB";
    }
} else {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB";
}
@sqlsrv_close($monsdbconn);
```

however it cannot find the characters, 
If I pick another part of the line and echo it, the characters show (since I set the default_encoding) but it cannot find it, and its painful as there are many trigger words in the list that I wish to find that are in korean.

Thanks in advance.

example of the file would be :

```
*아이템 5000 ec101 db120 da120 dg120
```

the ec101 etc is what I am trying to pilfer.

have tried mb_stripos unsuccessfully, and tried again with the code supplied below to no avail. it just doesn't find the text, 
however if I set it to find ec101 it will, but i can't guarantee that will be in the line so I used the preg_match but that only works for the drops, it wont work for all the other bits of information I am trying to find from the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stripos()` is not multibyte compatible. Instead you should use [`mb_stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php) which should work better for you. Also note that you need to check explicitly for a false result. A result of zero can also be interpreted as false.

```
$file = "c:\server\monster.inf";
$lines = file($file);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // convert to Unicode standard
    $line = mb_convert_encoding($line, "UTF-8", "EUC-KR");
    if (mb_stripos($line, "*아이템") !== false) {
        echo "$line\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that, its not finding it :/ 
im back at home now so i'll update post with the complete code (but strip out unnecessary stuff)

Comment: updated now, have tried it with and without the asterisk at the front of the korean characters, its got me baffled.

do I need to escape the asterisk if its within inverted commas?

Comment: I've just tested this code and it works fine. I would suggest your problem lies elsewhere. Are you certain this text is UTF-8 and not some legacy charset?

Comment: the code is from a program written back in 1998 so quite possibly. 

But i had run it through get_mb_charset and it returned utf-8, 
I put the whole code so that people could see if there was something extra im doing thats missing the point, i can reduce it if its causing any confusion

Comment: All I can say is I copied your sample Korean text as provided above into a text file, ran my PHP code, and it printed out that single line. I'm also not running PHP on Windows, if that makes a difference.

Comment: what php version are you running? I am running 5.3 
and mine is on iis so maybe that is affecting. 
i'll try it on my main server today and see if its windows 10 being crap.

Comment: I have 5.6 and 7.0 on macOS, both worked fine. 5.6 on Linux also worked fine. 5.3 has been EOL for 2.5 years, you should consider updating!

Comment: if it doesnt work on my server today i'll install 5.6 and try that.
is it possible that iis / windows would cause the issue?
Notepad wont read the charset correctly, I have to get them from notepad++ to get them as it stands
 Cheers.

Comment: Never ask a Mac or Linux user "is it possible that windows would cause the issue?" The answer is always yes! ;)

Comment: quick question, what settings have you set on your php?
I set default_encoding to UTF-8 (in php.ini) 
anything else that could affect it?

Comment: `default_charset="UTF-8"`

Comment: perhaps I need to link one of the original files, maybe np++ is corrupting it when it reads it.

Comment: Here is a link to an example file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B05zeMMSLAvmMjNFWUJBcXZPY28

Comment: That's using EUC-KR encoding, not UTF-8.

Comment: Yep, that works, thank you kindly, I hadn't thought to do the conversion on the line, I had tried to set the default charset to euc-kr but that hadnt worked. 

Many thanks :)

Comment: Hi @miken32 sorry to bump an older topic, do you know of a way to make mb_substr work with this? it seems that substr is about 6 chars in length (tested by echoing substr lengths), but can't make it match up with it.

Comment: You’d probably be better off asking a new question. Some charset guru would probably be able to help better than I.

Comment: worked it out, I had to convert the line to UTF-8 before I did the substr,  ` $lineUTF = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', 'EUC-KR');`